# Difficulty Trying to Refresh Page with PHP

Tags: php, html

With my limited HTML skills I've hacked together a crude bit of code to accomplish a simple task. I have a Raspberry Pi running an Apache webserver. On the Pi's monitor I need to display an image. Occasionally I will need to change that image remotely, switching between at most maybe a couple dozen images.

Right now in the same directory I have the image page, four .jpg files, and a 'chooser' page to select the image I want. I'm pulling this up on a different computer on the same network. The only way I could figure out how to pass the image I want was to write it to a text file. So the chooser page has a simple web form with some radio buttons and a submit button. You pick a number from 1 to 4, hit submit, and it simply writes that number to the text file. That part works.

The image page opens the text file, reads the number, and tacks it onto the img src tag. I made a simple loop that was refreshing the page every 5 seconds, and that worked fine. I could change the text file and a few seconds later the page would reload with the new image. Awesome.

So I tried to add a little extra code with the idea that instead of refreshing every 5 seconds, it would instead check every 5 seconds to see if the number in the text file was different.

Something about my code is janky, because the first time I load it nothing happens. The browser loading animation is going so I assume the code has started its loop, but if it got that far, why didn't it load the image first? It will churn along until I use the chooser page to change the text file. At that point, it will load the image, but it loads the number that was previously in the text file, not the current one. It works like this each time, always changing to the previous number, not the current one.

I'm sure it's something dumb that I don't understand because my coding skills suck. Anyone see the glaring error?

```
<?php
    $file = fopen("hints.txt","r");
    $theData = fread($file,2);
    fclose($file); 
?>

<img width=533 height=355 src="<?php echo $theData?>.jpg"><br>

<?php
    do{
        sleep(5);   
        $file2 = fopen("hints.txt","r");
        $theData2 = fread($file2,2);
        fclose($file2); 
    } while ($theData == $theData2);
    header("Refresh:0");
?>
```

Comment: It's something about how the actual page loads, isn't it? In my head I'm assuming that it does the first chunk of PHP code, then loads the image, then does the second chunk of PHP code, but that must not be how the browser parses the code. It's trying to do all the PHP code first which is why it's getting hung up in the loop immediately before it ever loads the image.

Answer (score 0):

Echo a bit of javascript to do it, as I recall headers can only be used before content is put onto the page.

```
<?php echo "<script>window.location.reload();</script>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your php code is trying to generate a page for the browser, but because you have a loop inside, it will hang there until data changes

Instead, you should poll hints.txt file with javascript ajax requests and update img source from the client side. Something like:

```
<!-- load source first time from file with php -->
<img width=533 height=355 id="image" src="<?php echo $theData?>.jpg" />


<script type="javascript">
window.setInterval(function(){
  //create ajax request object, not useful for IE
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  //you may want to change URL to this file
  xhttp.open("GET", "hints.txt", true);

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      console.log(xhttp.responseText); //see what response was

      //change image attribute
      document.getElementById("image").src = xhttp.responseText + '.jpg';
    }
  };
  xhttp.send();

//update every 5 sec
},5000);
</script>
```

Comment: So I copied your code into my page and it didn't work. I wanted to try and figure out what was going on, so I started plugging each item I didn't understand into w3schools.com and reading about what was happening. After messing around with it for quite some time and comparing it to the examples I saw, the only thing I saw that was different was that in yours you  used the type=javascript, and they didn't. So I deleted it. And it works perfectly. Thank you very much for the help. I really appreciate it!